# Repeating a set of <td>s in the same table row using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to create a table that, in its header, contains the names of each player for two teams in each . The scope has a variable `teams` which is a list of Team objects, each one having  list of Player objects as an attribute.

This is turning out to be way harder than I expected.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <div ng-repeat="team in teams">
        <th ng-repeat="player in team.players">{[ player.name ]}</th>
        <th>Partial Score</th>
        <th>Total Score</th>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

is the easiest thing I have in mind - but this doesn't work.  can't be placed inside a  according to W3C (from what I understand), so the browser just takes the div and places it outside the table.

I've tried directives as well - but these don't help. This is an example of my directive file.

```
<th ng-repeat="player in team.players">{[ player.name ]}</th>
<th>Partial Score</th>
<th>Total Score</th>
```

For example, if I have a `<player-initials>` directive with `replace: 'false'`, the browser expels the non-`<th>` element out of the table. Setting `replace: 'true'`, fixes that, but then I get an error because there's more than one root element in the directive. I can't wrap the elements in the directive with anything because that would result in invalid HTML (as above).

I've tried all combinations of element and attribute directives and replace, nothing gives me what I want. Any help?

Comment: I can't see a solution for this that will be W3C compliant. You would have to combine the team.players arrays into a players array and repeat on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end directives. I really didn't want to write functions to generate HTML for me, because that's why I switched to Angular in the first place.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsPnb.png.

This is the (stripped-down to relevant part) code just for the header, everything else is similar. The only 'hacky' part I don't like is the ng-show attributes for B and T to reverse it properly, but it works for me right now. I think I can get clean it up with directives.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat-start="team in game.getTeams()" ng-hide="true"></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="player in team.getPlayers()" ng-class="$parent.$first && 'text-info' || 'text-danger'">
                        <u>
                            {[ player.name | truncate ]}
                        </u>
                    </th>
                    <th ng-repeat-end ng-show="$first">
                        #
                    </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a method to your scope that do the logic for you.

Something like this should work:

```
$scope.getAllPlayers = function() {
    var players = [];
    this.teams.forEach(function(team){
        players = players.concat(team.players);
    });
    return players;
}
```

Then in your dom:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="player in getAllPlayers()">{{ player.name }}</th>
        <th>Partial Score</th>
        <th>Total Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I'm not using Angular so I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure this is the way to go. This kind of logic have to be in your controller, as simple is a nested loop.

**EDIT:** Referring to the comments, you could make a function that return your header cells the way you want them

```
$scope.getHeaderCells = function() {
    var cells = [];
    this.teams.forEach(function(team){
        cells = cells.concat(team.players.map(function(player){
            return { team: team, value: player.name };
        })).concat([
            {team: team, value: 'Partial Score'},
            {team: team, value: 'Total Score'}
        ]);
    });
    console.log(cells);
    return cells;
}
```

with

```
<th ng-repeat="cell in getHeaderCells()">{{ cell.value }}</th>
```

here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/456pe5ru/)

Comment: I also want to repeat Partial Score and Total Score for both the teams. I know that I could do all this by just specifically calling teams[0] and teams[1], but I want to do this more generally (to support more than 2 teams and general DRYness).

Comment: @quantumtremor then use the same process, logic to your controller. That said, I'm curious of what structure your table is supposed to have.

Comment: Say the players for team 1 are John, Tracy, and Michael, and the players for team 2 are Albert, Jill, and Taylor. Then the header would read
J T M **B T # T B** A J T, where B and T are bonus points and total score, and # is the column for question numbers.
The rest of the table is constructed similarly, but with special functions to get each player's points from the code.

Comment: Following the Angular doc you could use `ng-repeat-start` for this purpose.

Comment: I'm looking at that doc right now, but I'm not able to figure out how to do it. I have http://pastebin.com/7VhyjfxV right now, but I'm not sure how to get it to iterate the names of each player in the team.

Comment: Then you should make a function that return your header cells. Just call it differently :)

Comment: @quantumtremor updated answer, but I'd personally lay my table dynamic content vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: I ended up using ng-repeat-start to do it. A little bit hacky but works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/zgoknaxj/).

Hope this is what you are looking for, if not let me know the format that you are looking for. Your HTML should look something like below.

```
<table ng-repeat="team in teams">
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3"> 
            {{team.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Player Name</td> 
        <td>Partial Score</td> 
        <td>Total Score</td> 
    </tr>        
    <tr ng-repeat="player in team.players">
        <td>{{player.name}}</td> 
        <td>{{player.PScore}}</td> 
        <td>{{player.TScore}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's not what I'm looking for. Here's a image: http://i.imgur.com/b8J6Gj1.png. The underlined letters are the first letters of the player names (Toni, Stephen, Langston, Wallace for the first team and Witty, Schoppy, and Berty for the second team). The bonus and total (B and T) are team-dependent. The # just represents the column for the question number. I have functions to get each player/team's score for a specific question, I'm just not sure how to make the table.

Comment: Update the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/zgoknaxj/6/).
If you know that you have only 2 teams and players are dynamic then you can have the layout as in fiddle. You need to make the relationship between the questions and the scores by each team players to display

Comment: Thanks. I had something like that originally, but I didn't like all the code repeating. I figured it out though.